# How to Grab all contents inside Iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

what i need to do is that i want a Pdf of a book that is on google books.
each page of a book is coming through AJAX. but google provides iframe too
this is iframe of one i am looking for

```
<iframe id="iframeId" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:0px" src="http://books.google.com.pk/books?id=KOrTwnwcJ9IC&lpg=PP1&dq=magento%20books&pg=PT36&output=embed" width=500 height=500></iframe>
```

i want to grabe all the contents of this book put it in some div and than make a Pdf of it.i can do all but i just can't grab the contents

i tried this but saying id is not defined

```
  <Script type="text/javascript">

   var doc;
 if (document.getElementById(iframeId).contentDocument) {
   doc = document.getElementById(iframeId).contentDocument;
 }
 else if (document.getElementById(iframeId).contentWindow) { // older IE
  doc = document.getElementById(iframeId).contentWindow.document
  }

 if (doc) { alert(doc.body.innerHTML) }

</script>
```

in orignal iframe tag there was not id so than i manually write id for iframe tag that is id="iframeId"
but not working any idea ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the page loaded in the iframe is in the same domain you can have something like:

```
 var myIFrame = document.getElementById(iFrameName);
 var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
```

But Google also provides support for retrieveng info from google docs in JSON format:

https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample?hl=ro

And the second might be what you are looking for.